# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Status Report

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a simple REST API using spring boot. When i try to enter the URL on the browser however, i am getting the following error:

Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Please help me fix this error. [Also, this is the structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGqiG.png)

Here is my controller class:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

@GetMapping("/get")
public List<features> get() {
    features feature = new features();
    return feature.getList();
}
}
```

Here is my features class:

```
public class features {

private String cricketername;
private int runsScored;
private int iccRanking;
private String iplTeam;
private static List<features> list = new ArrayList<features>();
public features(){
    cricketername = null;
    runsScored=0;
    iccRanking=0;
    iplTeam=null;
}
public features(String name,int runs,int rank,String Team) {

cricketername = name;
runsScored = runs;
iccRanking = rank;
iplTeam = Team;
}
public void setCricketername(String name){
    cricketername = name;
}
public void setRunsScored(int runs){
    runsScored = runs;
}
public void setIccRanking(int ranking){
    iccRanking = ranking;
}
public void setIplTeam(String team){
    iplTeam = team;
}
public String getCricketername(){
return cricketername;
}

public int getIccRanking() {
    return iccRanking;
}

public int getRunsScored() {
    return runsScored;
}

public String getIplTeam() {
    return iplTeam;
}
static {
list.add(new features("Virat Kohli",10000,1,"RCB"));
list.add(new features("AB DE VILLIERS",20000,2,"rcb"));
list.add(new features("Kane williamson",2000,3,"SRH"));
}

public static List<features> getList() {
    return list;
}
public void add(String name,int runs,int rank,String team){
    list.add(new features(name,runs,rank,team));
}
```

}

POM.XML FILE:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demorRestAPI</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demorRestAPI</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: What's the url you are trying to reach?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/get